# Is there any way to see what Rarecrows you are missing?

Tags: stardew-valley

In Stardew Valley, you can get the Deluxe Scarecrow recipe after you get all other [Rarecrows](https://stardewvalley.fandom.com/wiki/Rarecrow).

Me and my significant other thought we got them all, but the game hasn't sent us the envelope with the deluxe recipe.

Is there somewhere to see if the game has registered if you gotten each Rarecrow?

Comment: Are you playing on a console where you have access to your save files?

Comment: Playing on PC. So yes

Comment: In the future, I recommend keeping all the rarecrows you've collected in a clump somewhere on your farm, organized by what number they are if possible. That way, you can just visit the clump to see what numbers are missing

Comment: Yeah, they are unsellable so they were in a chest somewhere. So we just did inventory with that and realised that one was missing. The opening the savefile thing worked to give a general idea, but was very complex and just gave us a little tip into which ones were seen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, the only way I know how to do this, is by checking your save file. Stardew Valley save files should be located at `%AppData%\StardewValley\Saves\` on Windows, and at `~/.config/StardewValley/Saves/` on MacOS and Linux.

The save file of the game you want to check should have a folder name like `Tink_241984836`, where the first part is the name of the player that created the farm map, and the second is just a random ID. Open the folder, and open the save file (that one should also be named `Tink_241984836`), I prefer using Notepad++ but any text editor that will also allow you to search for a specific string of text and count occurrences will do.

Once opened, do a count/search for `<hasBeenInInventory>true</hasBeenInInventory><name>Rarecrow</name>`. You can't just simply search for 'Rarecrow', because that won't return unique results. If you have found all the Rarecrows, this count should return '8'.

If the count there is lower, you can figure out which one you're still missing by doing a few more searches through your save file. Each Rarecrow in the game has a number that can be found [on the Modding:Big_craftables_data](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Modding:Big_craftables_data) wiki page. Their numbers are 110, 113, 126, 136, 137, 138, 139 and 140. They are ordered, so 110 is Rarecrow 1 of 8 and 140 is Rarecrow 8 of 8. Search your save file again, but this time for `<parentSheetIndex>138</parentSheetIndex>`, where the number `138` between the tags can be changed to match one of the above 8 numbers.

Once you figure out which number is missing, you can look at the [Rarecrow wiki page](https://stardewvalleywiki.com/Scarecrow#Rarecrows) to see an image of the Rarecrow you're still missing and where to find it.

Oh, and once you're done: Always close without saving. That's the best way to make sure you haven't accidentally messed up anything in your save file.

Comment: That kinda works... but that file is very hard to read. But idk if its our mods that screw up the readability of this  file.

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't think so, I never found the file easy to read... But then again, it's a save file, not a storybook :D If I do anything with the save file, it's always by using the search function, never by just reading it.

Comment: Yeah its looking like XML, but what I usually use to read XMLs just crash on load.

Comment: But yeah the complexity  might also come from the fact its a multiplayer game, so the savefile is doubled.

Comment: @Fredy31 Usually it helps to Ctrl+F for things based on specific values, like item names or how much money you know you have, etc. manually scrolling through any saved game file is typically a nightmare.

Comment: Yeah, Thats what I did. Thing is some have the hasBeenInInventory on true, others on false, others are just not there. It gave a general idea, but the whole thing was hard to read, even for someone who works in XML all day (I do HTML for a living lol)

Comment: It does give an ok idea, but its really hard to read.

Comment: Wait... @Fredy31 you have Rarecrows in your save file where the 'hasBeenInInventory' is false? Hmm. I checked a few of my saves, and all I found was the ones that had been in my inventory, I didn't see any that were 'false'. I wonder how that might happen (maybe you 'unlock' them after being able to buy them for the first time or something?) and if I should update the answer to mention that possibility then....

Comment: Think my file being a modded multiplayer game just screws up a lot of things. Thats why I flagged you as being a good answer.

Comment: @Fredy31 Hmm, yeah... if one of you had it in the inventory at some point and the other didn't, that might make sense :) I'll leave it as is then, people can read these comments to find out that if they play multiplayer, the count can be larger than 8 rarecrows but still mean there's one missing :P

Comment: Yeah I should check back now that I held the 7 we have in inventory for a minute if it will give me the rarecrows as <hasbeenininventory>